# AWS cognito libraries and android support

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have been struggling for a while now to get a gradle file that will build with the following:

```
compile('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-userpools:2.6.0@aar') { transitive = true; }
compile('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-ui:2.6.0@aar') { transitive = true; }
compile 'com.android.support:design:<absolutely any version>'
```

No matter what version I use, I can't get the three things to play nicely. The first two were taken directly off of amazons tutorial on integrating user sign-in (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile-hub/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-user-sign-in-email-and-password.html). The last I am using for the rest of the app (seems like a pretty standard, expected library to compile with???).

I have tried the following versions for com.android.support:design:
24.2.0: leads to the error:

```
All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 24.2.0, 23.0.0
```

23.0.0 also leads to the same above error.

Note:
Commenting out the userpools library allows v23.0.0 to work. Commenting out the auth-ui library allows v24.2.0 to work...

Answer (score 0):

Exclude the Android support libraries that are part of the dependencies.

For example, if your compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion are 24, you would be requiring the 24.+ support libraries

In build.gradle, do the following changes under dependencies:

```
.......
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.+'
.......

compile('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-ui:2.6.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'cardview-v7'
}
compile('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-userpools:2.6.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```